# MongoDB query - Get only selected objects from same or different documents

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I need a little help. I have a collection which has a field **dimension** and that field contains an array of different objects, which looks like this:

Collection - 1:

```
[
  {
    "_id": {
      "$oid": "6423cddbf4db0d397b22390a"
    },
    "dimension": [
      {
        "_id": {
          "$oid": "6423cde4f4db0d397b22390b"
        },
        "dimensionChild": "Wedding"
      },
      {
        "_id": {
          "$oid": "6423ce0af4db0d397b22390c"
        },
        "dimensionChild": "Business Casual"
      },
      {
        "_id": {
          "$oid": "6423ce18f4db0d397b22390d"
        },
        "dimensionChild": "Formal"
      }
    ]
  },
......
]
```

and in another object where I have available ids from the above document (collection - 1) in the form of array, which looks like this:

Collection - 2:

```
[
  {
    "productTags": [
      {
        "$oid": "6423ce0af4db0d397b22390c" // id from above doc
      },
      {
        "$oid": "6423b723f226c91a55d756bc" // id from different document
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Now I need some data like below:

```
[
  {
    "_id": {
      "$oid": "6423ce0af4db0d397b22390c"
    },
    "dimensionChild": "Business Casual"
  },
  {
    "_id": {
      "$oid": "6423b723f226c91a55d756bc"
    },
    "dimensionChild": "Business Casual 2"
  }
]
```

I was using the aggregation pipeline to fetch that and my attempt was something as below:

```
await MODEL.aggregate([
   .....,
    {'$lookup': { "from": 'TEAGET_COLLECTION', "localField": 'productTags', "foreignField": 'dimension._id', as: 'dimensions' } },
   .....,
])
```

and this actually returned me the whole "Collection - 1"'s dimension and also those records whose id was not present in "Collection - 2"'s `productTags`.

Can anyone please help me to know more about this query?

Thanks,
Soham Roy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Collection 1 joins with collection 2. The output for this stage will be the document with a `dimensions` array.
2. As `$lookup` stage in MongoDB is LEFT JOIN. To perform join, you have to filter the document with `dimensions` is not an empty array.
3. Set the `productTags` field by concatenating nested array from `dimensions.productTags` into an array via `$reduce`.
4. Filter the `dimension` array with the document that its `_id` is existed in the `productTags` array.
5. `$unwind` - Deconstruct the `dimension` array into multiple documents.
6. `$replaceWith` - Replace the input document with `dimension` object.

```
db.col1.aggregate([
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "col2",
      "localField": "dimension._id",
      "foreignField": "productTags",
      as: "dimensions"
    }
  },
  {
    $match: {
      dimensions: {
        $ne: []
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $set: {
      productTags: {
        $reduce: {
          input: "$dimensions",
          initialValue: [],
          in: {
            $concatArrays: [
              "$$value",
              "$$this.productTags"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $set: {
      dimension: {
        $filter: {
          input: "$dimension",
          cond: {
            $in: [
              "$$this._id",
              "$productTags"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$dimension"
  },
  {
    $replaceWith: "$dimension"
  }
])
```

[Demo @ Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/c-LCjt7sTcU)

Comment: I been trying to follow this yet no luck. here I'm putting the full schema and the query that I'm using. Can you pls check the gis repo. https://github.com/SohamRoyNoel/mongo-query/tree/master

Comment: Use your sample data and it seems work. [Demo](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Vx2_caLRnco)

Answer (score 0):

Another option is:

```
db.collection1.aggregate([
  {$lookup: {
      from: "collection2",
      localField: "productTags",
      foreignField: "dimension._id",
      as: "collection2"
  }},
  {$project: {
      dimension: {$filter: {
          input: "$dimension",
          cond: {$in: [
              "$$this._id",
              {$getField: {input: {$first: "$collection2"}, field: "productTags"}}
          ]}
      }}
  }},
  {$unwind: "$dimension"},
  {$replaceRoot: {newRoot: "$dimension"}}
])
```

See how it works on the [playground example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/qTjKeOG_Yvj)

Comment: I been trying to follow this yet no luck. here I'm putting the full schema and the query that I'm using. Can you pls check the gis repo. https://github.com/SohamRoyNoel/mongo-query/tree/master